# Cannot Change Styled Components Theme Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, node-modules, styled-components, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to fork the [PancakeSwap exchange interface](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-interface-v1) from GitHub and add my own styling to it. The problem is I haven't found a way to change the header nav panel as well as 80% of the rest of the react ts components.

I've followed multiple tutorials and have been reading up on typescript's styled-component [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) but I haven't been able to find any examples or documentation that is similar to Pancakeswap's ThemeProvider setup.

The **core** theme provider code that is used is: **[pancake-uikit](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-uikit)** - Here is where all my confusion lies and where I haven't been able to find any documentation for this type of theme setup.

If you visit the **[pancake-uikit](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-uikit)** repository I linked for Pancakeswap, you can see all of the core styled-components related code.

**To make my question easier to understand I will provide a Diagram of my project setup:**
[image]

**Here is a picture of pancakeswap:**
[image]

**Here is a picture of of what I've been able to change:**
[image]

The github repo for my code is here: https://github.com/CJ-Miller/andromeda-swap

I know this is a very open-ended question but I'm on week 2 of trying to get this to work and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To customize theme colors, you just need to tweak the `theme` that you're giving to your `SCThemeProvider` (in `src/ThemeContext.tsx`). Here's an example of how to change the background colors for `Card` components:

```
// src/ThemeContext.tsx

import { ThemeProvider as SCThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import {
  light as lightBase,
  dark as darkBase,
  PancakeTheme
} from '@pancakeswap-libs/uikit';

// customize light theme
const light: PancakeTheme = lightBase;
light.colors.text = '#222';
light.card.background = '#f4f4f4';
light.card.cardHeaderBackground = {
  default: 'coral',
  violet: 'goldenrod',
  blue: 'aquamarine'
};

// customize dark theme
const dark: PancakeTheme = darkBase;
dark.colors.text = '#444';
dark.card.background = '#111';
dark.card.cardHeaderBackground = {
  default: 'bisque',
  violet: 'chartreuse',
  blue: 'blueviolet'
};

// ...

const ThemeContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  // ...

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ isDark, toggleTheme }}>
      <SCThemeProvider theme={isDark ? dark : light}>{children}</SCThemeProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
};
```

You can use the same method to customize all other components. You can check the component file in `@pancakeswap-libs/uikit`, or you can just look at the `PancakeTheme` interface to see what properties are available. Note that some properties are constant (typed as `string`) while others depend on different variants (like `cardHeaderBackground` above, they'll be typed as objects where each key corresponds to a different variant).

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pancakeswap-libsuikit-custom-theme-3yt0k) with a simple demo.

Answer (score 2):

Most projects are changing the theme by forking the @pancakeswap-libs node_module.

If you look inside the uikit/dist folder there is a file named index.esm.js.

Most of the styles for the light and dark theme are on lines 2774 - 2791 and looks like this.

```
var baseColors = {
failure: "#ED4B9E",
primary: "#537f91",
primaryBright: "#537f91",
primaryDark: "#537f91",
secondary: "#787878",
success: "#31D0AA",
warning: "#FFB237",

var lightColors = __assign(__assign(__assign({}, baseColors), brandColors), { background: "#FAF9FA", backgroundDisabled: "#E9EAEB", contrast: "#191326", invertedContrast: "#c1dec0", input: "#eeeaf4", tertiary: "#EFF4F5", text: "#537f91", textDisabled: "#BDC2C4", textSubtle: "#537f91", borderColor: "#E9EAEB", card: "#FFFFFF", gradients: {
    bubblegum: "linear-gradient(139.73deg, #E6FDFF 0%, #F3EFFF 100%)",
} });
var darkColors = __assign(__assign(__assign({}, baseColors), brandColors), { secondary: "#FFFFFF", background: "#343135", backgroundDisabled: "#3c3742", contrast: "#FFFFFF", invertedContrast: "#191326", input: "#483f5a", primaryDark: "#0098A1", tertiary: "#353547", text: "#ffff", textDisabled: "#666171", textSubtle: "#ffff", borderColor: "#524B63", card: "#27262c", gradients: {
    bubblegum: "linear-gradient(139.73deg, #313D5C 0%, #3D2A54 100%)",
} });
```

I found one other color variable on line 1746.

Here is an example of how another project added their forked node_module to their package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
"@binance-chain/bsc-use-wallet": "^0.8.1",
"@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",
"@crowdin/crowdin-api-client": "^1.10.1",
"@ethersproject/abi": "^5.0.7",
"@pancakeswap-libs/uikit": "veganswap-defi/vegan-uikit",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
"@types/react": "^17.0.0",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
```

Here's a link to that repo https://github.com/veganswap-defi/vegan-frontend-farms/blob/master/package.json